# Insert statement MySQL via python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python script that adds a video url and time to my videopost table in DB. This is my 3rd script at python. I am still learning. Also please tell me how to lower the execution time of this script.

Code:

```
  #!/usr/bin/python
  import MySQLdb
  import sys

  db = MySQLdb.connect (host = "host.com", user="myusername",passwd="pass", db = "dbname")

  cursor = db.cursor ()
  db.query("SELECT now()")
  result = db.use_result()
  time= str("%s" % \
      result.fetch_row()[0])
  print time
  db.close()
  cursor =db.cursor()
  vidurl = raw_input("Enter the URL to the video:")
  print vidurl

  cursor.execute ("""INSERT INTO videopost(vidurl, time) VALUES (%s, %s)""", (vidurl,time))
  db.commit()
  db.close()
```

The error i am getting in this is

```
  File "vidup.py", line 28, in <module>
  cursor.execute ("""INSERT INTO videopost(vidurl, time) VALUES (%s, %s)""", (vidurl,time))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-freebsd-8.2-RELEASE-amd64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 155, in execute _mysql_exceptions.InterfaceError: (0, '')
```

Well thanks for the help. For people looking for solution i am posting the correction below:

```
  cursor.execute("SELECT now()")
  result = cursor.fetchall()
  time= str("%s" % \
        result[0])
  print time
  vidurl = raw_input("Enter the URL to the video:")
  print vidurl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the connection and then trying to grab a cursor:

```
db.close()
cursor =db.cursor()
```

Remove the first line and everything should work.

Comment: It's giving a command out of sync error

Complete Report : ` python vidup.py
2012-12-16 11:08:38
Exception _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now") in <bound method Cursor.__del__ of <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x11b48f50>> ignored
Enter the URL to the video:http://youtube.com
http://youtube.com `

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited the my question with a solution based on your answer and my own little tweak. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use:

```
cursor.execute ("""INSERT INTO videopost(vidurl, time) VALUES (%s, NOW())""", (vidurl,))
```

Comment: I wanted to display time right at the beginning. So that's why i used that. Then i moved onto passing that time value to a variable.
Well thanks anyway. I am still learning python.